# I want to edit footer credits in my footer. I am using the Whitedot theme. This is the code of my footer.php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer

I want to edit footer credits in my footer. I am using the Whitedot theme. I previously used generate press and I was able to do it with through funtions.php instead of footer.php
I want to know what can be done in this case and code that I can add.

```
    <!-- </div> --><!-- .col-full -->
</div><!-- #content -->

<?php
/**
 * whitedot_before_footer hook.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
do_action( 'whitedot_before_footer' ); 

?>

<footer itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter" itemscope class="site-footer">

    <?php
    /**
     * whitedot_before_footer_content hook.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'whitedot_before_footer_content' ); 

    /**
     * Functions hooked in to whitedot_footer_content action
     *
     * @hooked whitedot_footer_branding   - 10
     * @hooked whitedot_footer_widgets   - 20
     * @hooked whitedot_footer_info       - 30
     */
    do_action( 'whitedot_footer_content' );
      
    /**
     * whitedot_after_footer_content hook.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'whitedot_after_footer_content' );
    ?>
    
</footer><!--.site-footer-->

<?php
/**
 * whitedot_after_footer hook.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
    do_action( 'whitedot_after_footer' ); 

?>
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Be specific

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that is generated for the footer? I would try removing the do_action( 'whitedot_after_footer_content' ); and see what disappears from the footer, so you can at least idenfity what does what. I suspect the credit would be in the whitedot_footer_info() function

Comment: @JohnFotios l Hello, thanks for answering guys. I tried commenting /** the do_action( 'whitedot_after_footer_content' ); but nothing actually happened. It was just same.

Comment: Does it change if you delete all of the contents of footer.php? Just wondering if it's a caching issue.

Comment: @JohnFotios in that case site goes into critical error mode. When I comment/* the do_action( 'whitedot_footer_content' ); then whole footer gets invisible.

Comment: In that case site goes to critical error mode

Comment: I should have said delete the contents inside the `<footer>` tag. I will provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the contents of the footer tag to:

```
<footer itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter" itemscope class="site-footer">

    <?php
    do_action( 'whitedot_before_footer_content' ); 
    
    whitedot_footer_widgets();
    whitedot_footer_info();
    
    do_action( 'whitedot_after_footer_content' );
    ?>
    
</footer><!--.site-footer-->
```

The function `whitedot_footer_branding()` is attached to the action hook
`do_action( 'whitedot_footer_content' );`. I have removed the action and called the other functions directly.

This should remove the credit. Without seeing the theme or the html generated on the front end I can't know for sure what `whitedot_footer_branding()` does, it may include some other markup (such as a container) which when removed causes the layout to break.

Answer (score 0):

login to your cpanel or theme editor on wordpress and follow the steps:

Go to : public_html > wp-content > themes > whitedot > inc > hooks > general-hooks.php > line 443

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).